# Why can't I use my column alias in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, column-alias

I want to compare a value of my current row with the value of the row before. I came up with this, but it won't work. It can't find `PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE` so my `WHERE` clause is invalid. I'm not allowed to use `WITH`. Does anyone have an idea?

```
SELECT
   ID
   ,NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 
   ,LAG(NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
   ,DATE 
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM DATAFRAME
   WHERE DATE>=CURRENT_DATE-90
   ORDER BY DATE DESC
) AS InnerQuery
WHERE NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE <> PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
```

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the column alias is created.

Comment: Solution: Another _derived table_.

Comment: And also `LAG` runs on the resultset after the `WHERE` has run so it wouldn't make sense to be able to reference it in the `WHERE`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a complete beginner so two questions come to my mind. Is there another way o compare values from a row after or before? And if there is the need of a derived table, how do I go about it if I can't use with?

Comment: What do you mean "I'm not allowed to use WITH" - why not?

Comment: I am an intern and my boss told me to not use it :(

Comment: Well you can use another derived table but IMO using `WITH` gives clearer code. You should find out why. Maybe your boss has some misconceptions about it

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `order by` in the derived table ("InnerQuery") is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with your query:

- The filtering conditions should be in the *outer query*.
- The new column definition should be in the *inner query*.
- The `order by` should be in the *outer query*.

With these changes, it should work fine:

```
SELECT ID, NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE, PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE, DATE
FROM (SELECT D.*,
             LAG(NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
      FROM DATAFRAME D
     ) AS InnerQuery
WHERE NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE <> PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE AND
      DATE >= CURRENT_DATE - 90
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

You need the filtering *after* the `LAG()` so you can include the earliest day in the date range.  If you filter in the inner query, the `LAG()` will return `NULL` in that case.

You need to define the alias in the subquery so you can refer to it in the `WHERE`.  Aliases defined in a `SELECT` cannot be used in the corresponding `WHERE`.  This is a SQL rule, not due to the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You could use common table expression (CTE's) to split the query processing.

Something like this:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT * -- field list is advised...
  FROM DATAFRAME
  WHERE DATE >= CURRENT_DATE-90
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT ID
        ,NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 
        ,LAG(NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
        ,DATE 
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT ID
      ,NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 
      ,PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
      ,DATE 
FROM cte2
WHERE NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE <> PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Logical query processing is the conceptual interpretation of the query that defines the correct result, and unlike the keyed-in order of the query clauses, it starts by evaluating the FROM clause. Understanding logical query processing is crucial for correct understanding of T-SQL.

The main statement used to retrieve data in T-SQL is the SELECT statement. Following are the main query clauses specified in the order that you are supposed to type them (known as “keyed-in order”):

- SELECT
- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY

But as mentioned, the logical query processing order, which is the conceptual interpretation order, is different. It starts with the FROM clause. Here is the logical query processing order of the six main query clauses:

- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- SELECT
- ORDER BY

You can use a CTE :

```
  WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT * FROM DATAFRAME
       WHERE DATE>=CURRENT_DATE-90
       
),
CTE2 AS (
SELECT
       ID
       ,NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE 
       ,LAG(NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
       ,DATE 
    FROM CT2
)

SELECT * FROM CT2
WHERE NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE <> PREV_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `lag()` into the derived table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          number_of_people, 
          lag(number_of_people) over (order by date) as prev_number_of_people, 
          date
   FROM dataframe
   WHERE date >= current_date - 90
) AS InnerQuery
WHERE number_of_people <> prev_number_of_people 
ORDER BY date DESC
```